# Selecting the closest points alternating group lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Here I am stating an initial point as a reference:

```
pInitial={0,0};
```

These are the points that belong to the group P:

```
groupP={{255,510},{160,250},{560,246}};
```

These are the points that belong to the group ABC:

```
groupABC={{473,437},{430,388},{175,138}};
```

**How to create the following sequence?**

1 - Create an arrow that starts at point `pInitial`.

2 - From this point to look for which point of the `P group` is closest.

3 - Then from this `point P` do search which point of the `ABC group` is closest.

4 - So from this point of the `ABC group` to find which point of the `P group` are closer and thus until the final.

The code below shows the idea. I created knowing what is the sequence to be followed. I did this manually.

```
gpInitial=Graphics[{Black,PointSize[0.04],Point[{0,0}]}];
gABC=Graphics[{Green,PointSize[0.03],Point[groupABC]}];
gP=Graphics[{Blue,PointSize[0.03],Point[groupP]}];
gArrow=Graphics[{Red,Arrowheads[0.05],Thickness[0.008],Arrow[{{0,0},{160,250},{175,138},{255,510},{430,388},{560,246},{473,437}}]}];
Show[{gpInitial,gP,gABC,gArrow},Axes->True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I believe that I have understood your idea. Would review the groups always looking for the nearest to the next group.

```
pInitial={0,0};
groupP={{255,510},{160,250},{560,246}};
groupABC={{473,437},{430,388},{175,138}};
```

Here I am preserving the initial values of the graphics:

```
gpInitial=Graphics[{Black,PointSize[0.04],Point[{0,0}]}];
gABC=Graphics[{Green,PointSize[0.03],Point[groupABC]}];
gP=Graphics[{Blue,PointSize[0.03],Point[groupP]}];
```

Here were separated values `x` and `y` from `group P`

```
px=groupP[[#,1]]&/@Range[3];
py=groupP[[#,2]]&/@Range[3];
```

Were created twos lists with distances in `x` and `y` from `group P` with respect to the `pInitial`

```
Δx=px[[#]]&/@Range[3]-pInitial[[1]];
Δy=py[[#]]&/@Range[3]-pInitial[[2]];
```

Here only one example how to obtain the closest distance

```
distMin=Min[Sqrt[Δx[[#]]^2+Δy[[#]]^2]&/@Range[3]]//N
```

Another option would be to use [EuclideanDistance](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EuclideanDistance.html)

```
Min[EuclideanDistance[pInitial,groupP[[#]]]&/@Range[3]]//N
```

The function below calculates what position in the `Group P` is the closest point and what the `value` of this distance

```
f[i_]:={pos=Position[EuclideanDistance[pInitial,groupP[[#]]]&/@i,Min[EuclideanDistance[pInitial,groupP[[#]]]&/@i]],Extract[(EuclideanDistance[pInitial,groupP[[#]]]&/@i),First@pos]};
sol=Flatten@f[Range[3]]//N
```

With the position in the 'Group P' found it applies the value for 'p1':

```
p1=groupP[[First[sol]]]
```

Now we will remove the point from the list used

```
groupP=Drop[groupP,{First[sol]}]
```

Now `p1` is the new reference point. Until this moment I wanted to show the steps in greater detail. Now another possibility is to get positions through functions entering the new starting point and the group of points to be analyzed.

Where, `pI` is the new point and`pG` is the group of points.

```
f[pG_,pI_]:={pos=Position[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]],Min[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]]],Extract[(EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]),First@pos]};
sol=Flatten[f[groupABC,p1]];
p2=groupABC[[First[sol]]];
groupABC=Drop[groupABC,{First[sol]}];
f[pG_,pI_]:={pos=Position[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]],Min[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]]],Extract[(EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]),First@pos]};
sol=Flatten[f[groupP,p2]];
p3=groupP[[First[sol]]];
groupP=Drop[groupP,{First[sol]}];
f[pG_,pI_]:={pos=Position[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]],Min[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]]],Extract[(EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]),First@pos]};
sol=Flatten[f[groupABC,p3]];
p4=groupABC[[First[sol]]];
groupABC=Drop[groupABC,{First[sol]}];
f[pG_,pI_]:={pos=Position[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]],Min[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]]],Extract[(EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]),First@pos]};
sol=Flatten[f[groupP,p4]];
p5=groupP[[First[sol]]];
groupP=Drop[groupP,{First[sol]}];
f[pG_,pI_]:={pos=Position[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]],Min[EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]]],Extract[(EuclideanDistance[pI,Evaluate@pG[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[pG]]),First@pos]};
sol=Flatten[f[groupABC,p5]];
p6=groupABC[[First[sol]]];
groupABC=Drop[groupABC,{First[sol]}];
seq={pInitial,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6}

gArrow=Graphics[{Red,Arrowheads[0.05],Thickness[0.008],Arrow[{seq}]}];
Show[{gpInitial,gP,gABC,gArrow},Axes->True]
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this code.

Comment: I liked the explanation. Well detailed, but a bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 4):

This uses `Nearest` inside a `While` loop,

```
pInitial = {0, 0}; 
groupP = {{255, 510}, {160, 250}, {560, 246}};
groupABC = {{473, 437}, {430, 388}, {175, 138}};
path = Module[{pInitial = pInitial,
    groupP = groupP,
    groupABC = groupABC
    },
   Join[
    {pInitial},
    Reap[
      While[Length[Join[groupP, groupABC]] > 0,
        pInitial = First@Nearest[groupP, pInitial];
        Sow[pInitial];
        groupP = Complement[groupP, {pInitial}];
        pInitial = First@Nearest[groupABC, pInitial];
        Sow[pInitial];
        groupABC = Complement[groupABC, {pInitial}];
        ];
      ][[2, 1]]
    ]
   ];
Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Black, Point@pInitial, Blue, Point@groupP, 
  Green, Point@groupABC, Red, Line@path}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I really wanted to write a two-line `FoldList` implementation, but I failed to do so.....